# Check if column value is Numeric. SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a column with datatype of `varchar`. I would like to replace all the values that are not numeric with `NULL`.

So for example my column can contain a value of `MIGB_MGW` but also `1352`. The current expression I am using with `Derived Column Transformation Editor` is:

```
(DT_I4)kbup == (DT_I4)kbup ? 1  : 0
```

But of course this replaces all the values I want to keep with `1`. What expression would I use to keep the numeric values? (`1352` in this example)

Comment: `case when isnumeric(dt_i4) then dt_I4 else null end`

Comment: SSIS data flows (within which the Derived Column Transformation Editor is used) don't support ISNUMERIC as an inbuilt SSIS function, nor do they directly support a CASE statement. So I don't think this idea would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a `null` of `varchar` type, you can use `NULL(DT_STR)`.  For a `DT_I4` you can use `NULL(DT_I4)` etc.

You can then use `(DT_I4)kbup` in place of your `1` to return the original `varchar` value that you want to keep, converted to a `DT_I4`:

```
(DT_I4)kbup == (DT_I4)kbup ? (DT_I4)kbup : NULL(DT_I4)
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the Error Output to `Ignore failure`

Answer (score 3):

You could just convert them with a Derived Column and then use the ignore failure option in the Error output.
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT LIKE`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN col
         ELSE NULL
       END as Only_Numeric
FROM   (VALUES ('MIGB_MGW'),
               ('1352')) tc(col)
```

**Result :**

```
Only_Numeric
------------
NULL
1352
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option if 2012+ is **Try_Convert()**

```
SELECT Try_Convert(float,col)
FROM   (VALUES ('MIGB_MGW'),
               ('2.6e7'),
               ('2.6BMW'),
               ('1352')) tc(col)
```

Returns

```
NULL
26000000
NULL
1352
```

Comment: Seriously down voter?  This answer was 32 months ago and is perfectly valid.

Comment: Not the down-voter (but still a bit of a thread necromancer!). I assume the negative vote is due to the question specifically mentioning “in SSIS” and that function does not exist (directly) there. It could not be applied to data from sources other than SQL Server, without first sending the value to a SQL Server instance in order to run the function.