# Convert field from nVarchar to Numeric, what sql function for perfomance on many rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm bringing into SQL Server 2012 an external db table which has about 2 million rows and a Comments field nvarchar(200).

1st step moves data into a Staging DB.
2nd step move data into a Data Warehouse, incremental load once a day will be about 10,000 rows.

When moving data to DW I want to also split out the numeric data from Comments field into a new column.

I'm thinking of using TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,col) but want to know if this is best function performance wise to use or another way.

Guessing best to do this with sql rather than in SSIS with an expression derived column?

I don't have access to system yet to test but thinking this over to plan.

Comment: I think the ETL solution (SSIS) is generally better than transforming in T-SQL.

Comment: Yes I'd like to do in SSIS but was worried about performance... when you say do in SSIS would you think OK just checking with an expression or I should look to do the numeric check in a script task vb/c#?

Comment: Also to add I was going to put the TRY_CONVERT into SSIS in a Execute SQL Task when bringing the data in.

Comment: An SSIS script task is one method but there are other ways too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208685/check-if-column-value-is-numeric-ssis

Comment: Thanks Dan I'll take a look.